# Elasticsearch - update non indexed field

Tags: mongodb, search, elasticsearch, lucene, updates

I need to provide search functionality on my website and I intend to use Elastic Search for the purpose.

I have field A which remains constant, field B which changes, say, once every day and field C which changes every minute. Field C is not indexed (index: "no") while field A and field B are indexed.

Question: Will the whole document get updated (undergo retrieve-change-reindex process) whenever I change Field C (which is not indexed) in Elastic Search? Is Elastic Search a good choice for searching Fields A and B given the update frequency of Field C (other option could be MongoDB Text Search)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB is a database whereas Elasticsearch is a search engine.
It really comes to sense when manipulating these two systems: whereas MongoDB is all about flexibility with data, Elasticsearch has a bit more cautious and ordered approach.

Elasticsearch is a wrapper around the text search engine library Lucene. Schematically, Lucene manage low-level operation, as indexing and data storage, while Elasticsearch brings some data abstraction levels to fit JSON possibilities, an HTTP REST API and eases a lot the constitution of clusters.

Aggregations

The Elasticsearch request system is very homogeneous, and it becomes clear when dealing with aggregations.

MongoDB has a dedicated aggregation pipeline, defined through the stages [{"$match": }, {"$group": }, {"$sort": }, ...].
Elasticsearch aggregations are totally integrated into the requests,
and even if the request body is generally bigger than a MongoDB pipeline, it feels way clearer.

Elasticsearch strongly differs from MongoDB is that it is not schema-less.
It is possible to index document without any more information than the data alone, but the engine automatically maps the fields. When indexing a document,
Elasticsearch defines a default mapping for it. Once it's defined, it is not possible (unlike MongoDB) to index another document with the same type but a different format (with a string in a former int field for instance).

Mongodb will be faster than Elastic Search in bulk inserts with a default mapped index.

Documents in MongoDB are mutable whereas Documents in Elasticsearch are immutable; we cannot change them. Instead, if we need to update an existing document, we reindex or replace it.

[Updating Document in ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/update-doc.html)

[Partial Updating Document in ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html)

> Question: Will the whole document get updated (undergo retrieve-change-reindex process) whenever I change Field C (which is not indexed) in Elastic Search? Is Elastic Search a good choice for searching Fields A and B given the update frequency of Field C (other option could be MongoDB Text Search)?

Considering your frequency of updates and Elastic Search behavior of need to rebuild the document when there is a change. I would suggest to go for MongoDB

Comment: I have never faced a production use case where data type of a filed is changed . ElasticSearch is schema-less in it's own sense we have to model our use case around the indexing engine

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch is to go if you want to provide search capabilities reason

- Free Text Search
- Spatial Search
- Grouping , Aggregation
- Json Format
- Based on Lucene the best known indexing lib

If a filed is not indexed then you need to decide weather you want to store it? as if a field is neither stored nor indexed has no meaning and elasticsearch doc are immutable that means if you update a doc a new document gets created and updating a filed multiple times result in multiple version of same doc and requires reindexing though only one is active but puts pressure on system . If you have control on the Document ID of documents that are getting updated what you can do is just insert it again and again with same doc id and updated value

Comment: I wanted to store Field C as that would have allowed retrieval of Field C values from a single search request to Elasticsearch. If, however, I try to get values of Field C using MongoDB after Elasticsearch, then I run into another problem - [explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38389628/elasticsearch-and-subsequent-mongodb-queries#38390027)

Comment: ElasticSearch is not good if some field is getting updated on a regular basis . You have to design the system in a way like you keep the C field in Some cache like Redis and persist it in Mongo and when queried return it from Redis . MongoDB will act as persistent storage