# Elasticsearch and subsequent Mongodb queries

Tags: mongodb, search, mongodb-aggregation

I am implementing search functionality using Elasticsearch.

I receive  "username" set returned by Elasticsearch after which I need to query a collection in MongoDB for latest comment of each user in the "username" set.

Question: Lets say I receive ~100 usernames everytime I query Elasticsearch what would be the fastest way to query MongoDB to get the latest comment of each user. Is querying MongoDB 100 times in a for loop using .findOne() the only option?

(Note - Because latest comment of a user changes very often, I dont want to store it in Elasticsearch as that will trigger retrieve-change-reindex process for the entire document far too frequently)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer assumes following schema for your mongo db stored in `comments` db.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5788b71180036a1613ac0e34"),
  "username": "abc",
  "comment": "Best"
}
```

assuming `usernames` is the list of users you get from elasticsearch, you can perform following `aggregate`:

```
a =[
    {$match: {"username":{'$in':usernames}}},
    {$sort:{_id:-1}},
    {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "$username",
           latestcomment: { $first: "$comment" }
         }
     }
]
db.comments.aggregate(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

db.foo.find().sort({_id:1}).limit(100);

The 1 will sort ascending (old to new) and -1 will sort descending (new to old.)

Comment: The query above does not include usernames received from Elasticsearch results in any form!